# Returning metadata from .Read() and using it in a kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I'm using a grid with asp.net MVC. Currently the grid is using `.DataSource(c => c.Read())` to call a URL that returns an `IEnumerable<item>` which goes into the grid.

I want to implement paging in the grid. However the data does not have the normal method of paging (count, page number etc.).

Instead when I retrieve my data internally I get the data back like this:

`{ items: [. . . ], nextPage: 'J23jeg9e93', previousPage: 'oqow0r93285' }`

To get the next page you must make the request again for the data, but include the paging token for next or previous page.

At the moment I am only returning the items array to the grid, so no nextPage/previousPage metadata.

I can't see any way to include this metadata, as I am simply returning an IEnumerable of items so there is no wrapper object to put the metadata in.

I can use `.Data()` to attach metadata to the read request, but I need to do it the other way around. Once I get the metadata back I need to be able to store it in a javascript variable so that I can send it in `.Data()`

Comment: You need to, somewhere, add `nextPage` and `previousPage` info in your data before kendo parses it ?

Comment: The `Read()` command returns data like `[{name: 'bob', age: 23}, {name:'jim', age:43}...]` which goes into the grid. But I need to include metadata with next and previous page tokens. But I can't include it because I am only returning a list.

Comment: Unfortunately idk very well Kendo Asp.net framework, but in Javascript I believe there was two possible ways to do that: Adding your metadata in `dataSource.schema.parse` event; or in the `dataSource.transport.read` event, where you can use a function to make your own request and pass the data to the widget. There you could add the metadata. But I'm not sure if that can be done in Kendo Asp.Net. I believe it is possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are actually triggering the NextPage, PreviousPage operations, but...

You can use the MVC Custom DataSource configuration to provide access to more options like the Schema configuration. 
http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/custom-datasource

The Schema configuration allows you to add a Parse function that can take your custom result format:

```
{ items: [. . . ], nextPage: 'J23jeg9e93', previousPage: 'oqow0r93285' }
```

and extract the items(to give to the grid) AND the nextPage, previousPage values(for you to store to pass to the next read request).

For example:

Sample Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp4.Models.GridViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Custom()
    .Batch(true)
    .Schema(schema => schema
        .Parse(@<text>parseData</text>)
    )
    .Transport(transport => transport
        .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("readData"))
    )
    .PageSize(1)
    .ServerPaging(true)
)
.Pageable()
)
```

Sample parseData and readData javascript:

```
<script>
var nextPage,
    previousPage;
function readData() {
    // Return the "extra" data that should be posted with each grid read request, which is the nextPage/previousPage we were given in the previous request respsonse.
    return {
        nextPage: nextPage,
        previousPage: previousPage
    };
}
function parseData(data) {
    // Parse the response from the server as it isn't in the typical format expected by the grid.

    // Extract your nextPage/previousPage, store it somewhere so they can be added to the next grid request.
    nextPage = data.nextPage;
    previousPage = data.previousPage;

    // Return the actual data that should be displayed in the grid.
    return data.items;
}
</script>
```

Sample grid read action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Grid_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string nextPage, string previousPage)
    {

        // "Fetch" the data, presumably doing something with nextPage and previousPage...
        var items = new List<GridViewModel>()
        {
            new GridViewModel() { name = "bob", age = 23},
            new GridViewModel() { name = "jim", age = 43},
        };
        // Determine what the new nextPage, previousPage should be...
        var newNextPage = "J23jeg9e93";
        var newPreviousPage = "oqow0r93285";

        return Json(new
        {
            items = items,
            nextPage = newNextPage,
            previousPage = newPreviousPage
        });
    }
```

This is not a complete, robust solution, but I think it can be made workable and will at least point you in a possible direction.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I wanted to do. I'm also not sure how to tackle the next/previous buttons but I should be able to figure it out. I'm going to try this now.

Comment: One issue is occurring, which is that the .Data method to include my pageToken in the read request runs once the first time the grid is populated, and then never runs again - so the value sent is always the initial value (empty string). I'm refreshing the grid with `$('#messagesgrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#messagesgrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();`

Comment: Hmmm...well I just added a button to my sample project to trigger the .dataSource.read() and it is executing the readData and hitting my Grid_Read action each time, so I don't really know...

Comment: Did you use the exact same line as above to read and refresh?

Comment: Ah I've solved it all working, I put `data("readData()")` instead of `data("readData)"` - strange it worked the first time! Many thanks 100% working now :)

Comment: @NibblyPig - Also, please note that to reload the grid there is no need to call the _refresh_ method. Calling just the _read_ method is enough.

Comment: It worked the first time(and only the first time) because "readData()" is a function call that executes right away during grid initialization, whereas "readData" is a function "pointer"(or whatever the JS term is), not call, that sets the config up for execution every time.  A function call is different than a function.